# Why no data-* elements?

Tags: html, angularjs, visual-studio, element

This is a question to mostly satisfy my curiosity: with the growth and acceptance of larger javascript frameworks the last, say, 5 years, it has become increasingly common to have attributes on elements add custom behavior to known html elements. For this reason html5 introduces data-* attributes, which just about every tool, including the browser parsing the dom actively ignores while rendering but are key for Js framework to enrich html as full-fledged application platform.

With Angular directives (for example), app builders enrich html as a whole by adding the ability to even create custom elements. The thing is however, this is where editing tools, like Visual Studio, break, since they like to actively check if the html elements you add exist.

Now, my question is not about visual studio (I know how to disable html validation), but why did the creators of the html5 standard never considered to include data-* elements as well? Or maybe they did, and the idea was discarded somehow. Does anyone know?

Comment: +1. The closest thing we have now are `<script type='text/whatever'>` tags where you can stuff things in.

Comment: From what I know the `data-` was introduced in html5 and a lot of ppl use them, but IMHO most ppl use it only to pass html validation (i.e. w3c validator)

Comment: My understanding is that data- is for user defined tags, and should be ignored by validator tools.

Comment: Custom elements have, of course, been considered many times. You should check out [Web Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/) and the polyfill [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The `data-` prefix is actually part of the [HTML5 draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2A-attributes)

these attributes are for semantic HTML; as an example, attaching a database ID to an HTML element so that HTML parsers can use this data. In the case of Angular, the custom attributes do not carry data; they extend HTML.

Mozilla has some guidelines on the topic of the data prefix: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

**Edit** The intent of HTML elements is to carry *content* to be displayed by the browser, *attributes* to attach meta-data to these elements and `<head>` to attach meta-data to the whole document. There are no `data-` elements in HTML so it's consistent with that design.

Comment: I think he's asking about `data-` elements to pass validation, not attributes that he already knew.

Comment: Like Gildor said; my question is about elements, not attributes.

Comment: As far as I know, HTML5 doesn't allow (or prevent) the use of custom tags; they are pretty much considered like `div` elements. There are discussions for "web components" (http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/) that would allow custom tag, but I didn't see anything related to `data-` elements. In my very humble opinion, these tags would not make sense, as the HTML elements *are* the document data, so any descriptive meta-data like the `data-` attributes allow would not be provided as an element, only as an attribute.

Comment: If that helps, let me know and I'll develop this in my answer.

Comment: @Christian. The problem for me is in that situation "div data-something=" might just be intended for a javascript framework, but it's still rendered by the browser. A data-* element would/should be ignored all together.

Comment: Well, the intent of elements is to carry content to be displayed by the browser, attributes to attach meta-data to these elements and `<head>` to attach meta-data to the document. To your original question as to why there are no `data-` elements, that's to be consistent with that design.

Comment: Hi @ChristianRondeau, I'm looking over my past questions, could you put your comments above in an answer so I can mark it? Thx.

Comment: Comment moved in the body of the answer! :)